# What's the name of the Google Images search feature that show tags at the top that apply filters?

Tags: seo, google-image-search

[image]

What's the name of this Google Images feature that displays categories of products related to a website, e.g boohoo ?

I've seen relatively big fashion retail websites that didn't have this feature  and some smaller ones that had it, so what really needs to be done to make this work for your website ?

I know it works for other types of websites, I'm just using fashion retail websites as an example.

EDIT: To make it clear, I'm referring to the tags at the top that filter the content once you click on them. e.g When I click on the tag "sweater" it will only show images of sweaters from the website boohoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the feature is Google Images Badges. For it to be able to filter your products images you need to add special markup on the pages containing the products.

More information on https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/products.